# unable to add google captcha into custom frontend form

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I followed this URL https://magently.com/blog/recaptcha-in-magento-custom-form/ to add google captcha. I created secret keys in google account but unable to see on custom page

```
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Check the captcha code in the msp_recaptcha.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in Custom Form in below way : Add js Using RequireJS.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
         async defer>
      </script>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha256-sPB0F50YUDK0otDnsfNHawYmA5M0pjjUf4TvRJkGFrI=" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var onloadCallback = function() {
           grecaptcha.render('google_recaptcha', {
             'sitekey' : '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI'
           });
         };
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <form action="?" method="POST" id="loginForm">
         <div id="google_recaptcha"></div>
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         $("#loginForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                if (grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
                alert('Captcha Confirmed!');
                //form.submit();
                } 
                else {
                alert('Please confirm captcha to proceed');
                }
            }
         });          
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this blog it work : https://magebug.blogspot.com/2018/05/magento-2-add-google-recaptcha-in.html